# Uninstalling patch via powershell script (MSIEXEC)

Tags: powershell, parameters, patch, uninstallation, windows-installer

im kinda new to powershell and im trying to automate a uninstall patch so I can install another one (using jenkins etc~).

I have this script which gets the ProductID number and i have the path to the patch .msp file too. Passing these variables to the msiexec command doesn't work. I keep getting the error: "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists~'.

Although, if i run the command without passing the variables to the msiexec it works.

Heres my script:

```
    $PATHPreviousPatch = "<>" #this is where I keep the .msp files to the patch that im trying to uninstall

    $IdNumber = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -eq "%product Example%"} | Format-List -Property IdentifyingNumber
    $strProductCode = $IdNumber | Out-String

    $strProductCode -match "IdentifyingNumber : (?<content>.*)"
    $strProductCode = $Matches['content']

    [string]$AppMSP = Get-ChildItem $PATHPreviousPatch| Where-Object {$_.Name -match "%appmsp%.msp"}
    $fullUninstallPath = $PATHPreviousPatch + $AppMSP #just to get the full path to the MSP file

    msiexec /package `'$strProductCode`' /uninstall """$fullUninstallPath"""
```

Pls help, I've tried everything i could find..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not need to put quotes around the product code. When you say "if i run the command without passing the variables to the msiexec it works" do you mean if you just type the product code in at the command line?

Comment: You have a number of issues with your code.  For example, there is no need to use `Format-List` at the end of the first call.  This is giving you the wrong datatype in  `$IdNumber`, your `Where-Object` filter is performing an exact match against a pattern, the pattern you are using has `%` where it should have `*`, `Out-String` is unnecessary, and so on ...

Comment: If you know the patch that you want to remove, you don't need 90% of that code. You already know or can get the product code anyway.

Comment: @EBGreen yes, didnt explain that too well.. if i just get the last line 'msiexec~' and write-host it, then copy and paste the result, i am able to uninstall

Comment: Personally when I am workingwith command line issues I like to build the command line as a string then I can `Write-Host` the string to see what it looks like and `Invoke-Expression` the string to actually invoke it (although `Invoke-Expression` is frowned on but not horrible in this use case). So something like this `$cmd = 'msiexec /package {0} /uninstall "{1}"' -f $strProductCode, $fullUninstallPath`

Comment: @EBGreen it's me again, I did what you suggested. The product code only works (when passing all the values to console) when inside "". 
Like this: $cmd = 'msiexec.exe /package "{0}" /uninstall "{1}"' -f $strProductCode, $fullUninstallPath

Calling the Invoke-Expression on $cmd still gives the same error 'This installation package could not be opened'

Cant find what im doing wrong..

Comment: Hmmm...I've never had that issue, but if it works then do it that way.

Comment: Did you build the command the way I showed? If you did then add the quotes that you need and invoke it.

Comment: @EBGreen thanks for your patience..  I cant seem to make the command work passing the variables to it, it always return the same error If i type this to console, it works: msiexec.exe /package "{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX}" /uninstall "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MSPFile.msp" But this doesnt: $cmd = 'msiexec.exe /package "{0}" /uninstall "{1}"' -f $strProductCode, $fullUninstallPath Invoke-Expression $cmd

Comment: When you Write-Host $cmd does it look ***exactly*** the same as what you type that works?

Comment: Exactly, im copying it and then pasting to the console

Comment: Found the issue, when i create the $strProductCode passing the value it works. But receiving the value from $Matches['content'] doesnt. I will try to fix it, thanks again